# How can I see the log history of my iPhone 6 from an Android?

Tags: ios

Is there any way to view the call history and message history of my iPhone which I have given it to my daughter because she deletes everything every now and then. I can't check the mobile again and again as a father I can't do this.

Answer (score 1):

There's 2 ways to check the call history:

1. Look at the *Recent* tab in the Phone app.  This will tell you the numbers she's called and when she called.  To do this you need to have the physical iPhone with you and access to the Phone app.
2. Review the call log from your **cell provider**.  Almost all major cell providers allow you to log into your account from any browser or their app and review the call and text history.